# Нужно отобразить опредёленное количество информации Python3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как отображать определенное количество информации. я использую селениум

У меня отображается 15 элементов (на странице их 15). И мне нужно ограничить количество выводимой информации

```
url = "..."
driver.get(url=url)

with open('...') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

try:
    time.sleep(10)
    divs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "game-info")
    for div in divs:
        atag = div.text
        for x in content:
            print(x + "\n" + atag)
```

Comment: Ну, банально введите счетчик и прибавляйте каждый раз, когда вводите инфу. Если больше не нужно, то проверяйте значение счётчика и прерывание цикл (`break`)

Comment: Я не понимаю как это реализовать в коде

Comment: for x in content[0:5]

Comment: Оно выводит 5 результатов, по 5 раз